# Create a list from the document in the library

Tags: list, sharepoint-library, ms-project

I have a MS Project file uploaded to the document library on the site. I want to create two lists with the information retrieved from this document (Project tasks and Custom list). I need these two lists to be synchronised with the original document, so when I edit either a list or a document, both will be updated. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

For similar purposes we use [Event Receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx).
You could fire an event when an item is uploaded in the "parent" list, get the infos you need, and then load those info in the "child" list(s).

Here you can find a basic [implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437502(v=office.14).aspx) and some references.

Comment: Would you please elaborate your answer with more details on what you did and how you solve it, may be with some example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the workflow you will be using should be connected to the form in the Library. Then, in SharePoint Desighner when you edit the workflow, you choose which list you want the info to go to ( which could be either a Task list or customized List), and there you can also create your custom columns. To have a second list upload the same information you have to do the parents child aspect listed above.